# svg Polygon Points - Javascript - Not Working

Tags: javascript, svg, polygon

How can I control the points of a `svg` `polygon` via JavaScript? Tried solving it this way, but it does not work.

```js
function points() {
  document.getElementById("polygon").points = "0,100 0,0 100,100";
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <polygon id="polygon" points="0,0 100,0 100,100" style="fill:#000;">
</svg>
  
<input type="button" onClick="points" value="Change Polygon Points">
```

Comment: That's basically the same polygon so you'd never know whether the function did anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've changed the output polygon so that it looks different to the starting polygon, otherwise it looks like the code doesn't do anything.

```js
function points() {
  document.getElementById("polygon").setAttribute("points", "100,0 50,0 100,100");
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <polygon id="polygon" points="0,0 100,0 100,100" style="fill:#000;">
</svg>
  
<input type="button" onClick="points()" value="Change Polygon Points">
```

Comment: Yeah, messed it up a bit.. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('polygon1').setAttribute('points', '100, 0 50, 0 100, 100');
```